# Inequality induction proof with multiple variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

*For all $s ∈ N$ and all $k > 0$ it holds that $1+sk ≤(1+k)^s$*

How would one use induction to prove this statement?

Im following the basic steps: First do base case then do induction step but
i dont know how to even set the base case up correctly.
Im setting up RHS and LHS to prove base case, but im not sure how to do it
when there is multiple variables.

Comment: Hint: induction as we know it is on countable sets. Firsr set $s = 1$ to see what happens, then assume the statement holds for $s = m$, then try to prove for $m+1$.

Comment: ah okay so i should just worry about the "s" variable because its for that we are proving?

Comment: No, $s$ is indexed by the natural numbers, and that's what you induct on.

Comment: Okay i see, so how would i set up the RHS and LHS?

Comment: should i just replace both s and k with 1 for base case? in both LHS and RHS?

Answer (score 0):

For $s=1$, LHS$=1+k$, and RHS$=(1+k)$. Therefore the statement is true. Assume that it is true for $s=s'$. Then

$$
(1+k)^{s'+1} = (1+k)(1+k)^{s'} \geq (1+s'k)(1+k) = 1+k+s'k+s'k^2 \geq 1+(1+s')k.
$$

In the last inequality use the fact that $k>0$.

Comment: 0 is not part of natural numbers no? So i have to prove it for 1 base case, and im required to set up LHS and RHS i believe

Comment: You are right it is in general not considered as a part of the natural number. But your inequality is true for all non-negative integers! The base case $s=1$ is also trivial. Check!

Comment: do you know how i would set up LHS and RHS for bae case?

Comment: See the edited answer.

Comment: wouldnt it be $LHS = 1 + 1 * k$ and $RHS = (1+k)^1$

Comment: @EmilB yes, but both of those are equal to $1 + k$.

Comment: Ah yeah i see, would it be enough to write 1 +k ≤ (1+k) is true for base case? Or how would i show it?

Comment: Yes, that'd be enough to write.